# Difference in CSS transition on the same page

Tags: wordpress, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Im puzzled at why I'm getting a different transition of the same element on the same page dependant on scroll. Using Chrome-Mac

[DEMO](http://www.warface.co.uk/beta/)

1. Rollover the top black bar and notice it jerk in

[image: 1. Rollover]

2. Scroll to the top of the page and roll over to see a smooth desired transition

[image: 2.]

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
}    
#top:hover { 
        height: 60px;
        -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a difference in FF??

Comment: Did you get it working? I don't see an issue anymore.

Comment: @Rob What's up with the cat?

Comment: @JoshC you not like him? :)